# Multiplying two input variables jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a basic ROI calculator and having trouble getting any kind of math function to work. I will only require two user variable inputs and want my coding to pass through a simple math equation and post the answer. The math formula will change once I can get my two input variables to at least multiply against each other.

Upon hitting submit, no output is given and the input fields reset. Clicking reset does clear the fields. I want the input (#output) to display the answer.

I don't care about CSS or final formula at this point.

HTML Type:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="calculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="calculator">
        <input type="text" id="Occupancy" name="occupancy">
        <input type="text" id="rooms" name="rooms">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="reset" type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
        <input type="text" id="output" name="output">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code below:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculator').submit(function() {
        var occupancy = $('#Occupancy').val();
        var rooms = $('#rooms').val();
        var output =occupancy * rooms;
        output = output.toFixed(2);
        $('#output').val(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: Describe what happens vs. what's expected.

Comment: Upon hitting submit, no output is given and the input fields reset. Clicking reset does clear the fields. I want the input (#output) to display the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the line "output=output.toFixed(2);" does not populate the answer field after submitting values.

Comment: @JoelCornett Because of the multiplication, `typeof output` evaluates to "number" and therefor `toFixed()` is valid in this context.

Comment: @Wynand Ah I see. Silent type conversions are still something I'm getting used to in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script works fine. What happens is, the script runs and calculates the result. But then, the form is submitted to the server and reloads the page.

To prevent this, you must prohibit the form from submitting to the server

```js
$('#calculator').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var occupancy = $('#Occupancy').val();
    var rooms = $('#rooms').val();
    var output = occupancy * rooms;
    output = output.toFixed(2);
    $('#output').val(output);
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRS8N/)

Answer (score 0):

try to change

`var occupancy = $('#Occupancy').val();`

to `var occupancy = parseFloat($('#Occupancy').val());`

and `var rooms = $('#rooms').val();`

to `var rooms = parseFloat$('#rooms').val());`

Comment: Same results. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no requirement to submit the form:

```
$('#calculateButton').click(function() {
  var occupancy = $('#Occupancy').val();
  var rooms = $('#rooms').val();
  var output = +occupancy * +rooms;

  $('#output').val(output.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var occupancy = $('#Occupancy').val();
        var rooms = $('#rooms').val();
        var output =occupancy * rooms;
        output = output.toFixed(2);
        $('#output').val(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good idea, although the form will still submit and by default, clear the value of `output` on page reload.